# Match replace with regular expression and lookup table

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to match using regular expressions and replace a subgroup of the match using a result that I will lookup in a table using the subgroup as the key. How can I do that with powershell?

PowerShell version `3.0`

The following doesn't work, although `$hash` is a hashtable:

```
$string = '<author>A12345</author>' 
$string -replace '(<author>)([^<]+)', '$1$($hash[$matches[2]])'
```

Will output: `<author>$($hash[$matches[2]])</author>`

Thanks to the comments I now got that part to work.
My objective is to process the output of the svn command to map the authors

```
svn @args | ForEach-Object -Process {
If (($_ -match "(<author>)([^<]+)") -and ($users.ContainsKey($matches[2]))) {$_ -replace '(<author>)([^<]+)', "`$1$($users[$matches[2]])"} 
else {$_}}
```

What I'm missing now is that I want to set this as the new svn command in IntelliJ, therefore this PowerShell script needs either to be called directly or be called through a batch script and the arguments passed through. At the moment I'm using a batch script but for some reason it is not working with IntelliJ:

```
powershell " ""C:\tools\svnTools\selSvn.ps1 """ %*
```

Comment: Questions without code generally go to https://superuser.com/.

Comment: Show us an example what you want

Comment: You shouldn't use single quotes around strings that contain expandable variables. Change `'$1$($hash[$matches[2]])'` to "`$1$($hash[$matches[2]])". You need to escape the $ that represents the capture group since it is **not** a variable.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thanks, worked like a charm :) Now my next step is to apply this transformation to the result of another command. I guess using a pipe operator would be the way to go?

Comment: When it comes to piping, there are two sides. The side that feeds data into the pipe and the side that receives the data. The receiving side needs to be able to accept that output string. I can't speak to whether you should do that or not without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I edited the question and added the relevant details